# Are there any problems with hiding all my Excel range names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

Is there any problem with hiding my named ranges
I have a BIG project, over the years it has grown and grown and it has a lot of named ranges.

It will be used in Excel 2007, 2010 and 2013.

I now have to let colleagues use it and I want to hide all the named ranges except those that they are likely to use.

I have Jan Karel Pieterson's Name Manager, but I need to know what will happen when I hide all the named ranges. 
How will it affect code that uses them?
How will it affect formulas that use them?
or
will it just tidy everything up and everything will still work the same?

Comment: Q. did you try to hide some names and perform some tests to see if your formuas still behaves as expected??

Comment: Fully hiding stuff in Excel is challenging. How will you hide them? Is it possible to securely hide so no one can access?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience everything will work the same. But do as Brandin said, try it out and see.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with the names all hidden for a couple of weeks now and so far all is good. I'm still not convinced that I won't come across some arcane set of circumstances that cause me problems, but nothing yet. Thanks for all the answers.

M